# como validar campo data para se nao for passado nada vir a data atual

Tags: api, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Possuo um endpoint da seguinte forma:

```
[HttpGet]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<TestsDto>), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<TestsDto>>> GetAsync(Guid textId, Guid phraseId, Guid heightId, Guid? weightId, Guid? productId, decimal? value, DateTime? date)
{
    
    var test= await _testingHandler.GetAsync(textId, phraseId, currencyId, heightId, weightId, value, date );
    return Ok(apps);
}
```

Como eu faço para validar, se o ultimo campo que é `date` nao for passado valor algum pra ele eu atribuir sempre a data atual nesse campo ?

Comment: `date ?? DateTime.Now`?

Comment: @LINQ consigo passar direto no parametro tipo igual string, no caso `string algumacoisa = "" ` ? dessa forma a variavel é uma string porem se nao passar nada vem é atribuido vazio sempre. No caso da data nao consegui fazer

Answer (score 0):

Você quer fazer essa verificação apenas na API certo?
Não tem magica, você vai precisar criar um método ou apenas um condicional para verificar para você.

if (date == null)
date = DateTime.Now;

Ou você poderia criar uma classe de validação utilizando bibliotecas como a FluentValidation /AbstractValidator para realizar essa ação para você.

https://codigosimples.net/2018/11/14/usando-o-fluentvalidation-no-net-core/
https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/custom-validators.html

Answer (score -1):

Olá, veja se isso funciona para você:

```
[HttpGet]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<TestsDto>), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<TestsDto>>> GetAsync(Guid textId, Guid phraseId, Guid heightId, Guid? weightId, Guid? productId, decimal? value, DateTime? date)
{
    if (date == null)
         date = DateTime.Now;
    var test= await _testingHandler.GetAsync(textId, phraseId, currencyId, heightId, weightId, value, date );
    return Ok(apps);
}
```